# Find intersection between search text and jsonl file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to search and find the intersection between a search text and some `jsonl` file. An example is as follows:

Search text:

```
Alice goes to school
```

Jsonl file content:

```json
{"text": "Alice goes to market"}
```

Expected output:

```
Alice goes to
```

I tried to implement it using grep but didn't output the expected behavior.

Comment: I had no idea about `jsonl` files. Regarding your question is the `jsonl` file content you showed valid? And what about these texts: **Search**: `Alice went to school` , **Jsonl**: `Alice goes to market`, the expected output should be: `Alice to` (this is the intersection) or do you expect another output in that case?

Comment: the jsonl file is the same as JSON, the structure is the following: text:{Alice goes to market}. The search is the text that I want to find in the jsonl file. Yes, the expected output is the same as I mentioned

Comment: ```{"text": "It is done, and submitted. You can play \u201cSurvival of the Tastiest\u201d on Android,}``` here is some real example of the data, and yes the order matters

Comment: The structure of the data isn't the real problem I can parse it using some parser, but the point here that I can't do which is finding the intersection.

Comment: This might be useful: `grep -o -f <(echo  "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1) <(jq '.text' < example.json) | xargs`. However I'm not really sure if that does really make the intersection successfully (with your example works fine).

Comment: Yes, it works great, thanks. Put in an answer, please.

Comment: Great! First I will take a look if there are cases where this makes a  *wrong intersection* to detail them in the answer and if it's needed I'll provide alternatives (like `comm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the `json` content as you have:

**example.json**

```json
{"text": "Alice goes to market"}
```

Using this `grep` command seems to work:

```bash
grep -Fo -f <(echo  "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1) <(jq -r '.text' < example.json) | xargs
```

Where `grep`:

1. `-F` uses fixed-strings and avoid using `regex`.
2. `-o` is used to show only the matched string.
3. `-f` is used to specify the *pattern* file. In this case `grep` will search for this strings: `Alice`, `goes`, `to`, `school`

And `jq -r` shows the output as raw strings, not JSON texts. So instead of getting: `"Alice goes to market"` you will get: `Alice goes to market`

About `<(echo  "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1)` that's called **process substitution** and I used that instead of passing a file.
This command: `echo  "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1` displays the following:

```
Alice
goes
to
school
```

I also used **process substitution** here: `<(jq -r '.text' < example.json)` to get the content of your `text` json key. So what `jq -r '.text' < example.json` does is showing:

```bash
"Alice goes to the market"
```

Basically, what the full `grep` does is search each word: `Alice`, `goes`, `to`, `school` in string `"Alice goes to the market"`.

Finally I piped the output to `xargs` to get this output:

```
Alice goes to
```

If you do not pipe (`| xargs`) you will the output as *separated-lines*:

```
Alice
goes
to
```

---

**Other cases**

If your `json` file had this content:

```json
[
   {"text": "Alice goes to the market"}
]
[
   {"text": "Alice went to the market"}
]
```

Using the code above will result in a fail. So here, since `text` keys are in the first position (index 0) you easily use:

```
grep -Fo -f <(echo  "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1) <(jq -r '.[0].text' < example2.json) | sort -u | xargs
```

**Note that** I used `sort -u` before piping to xargs (`| xargs`). That because `grep` will show string *duplicates* because of the json above. If you remove `sort -u` you will get:

```
Alice goes to Alice to
```

---

#### Using `comm`

You can use `comm` command to get the intersections too. But you have to order the *file* (the lines) to be able to make use of this one:

```bash
comm -12 <(echo "Alice goes to school" | xargs -n1 | sort) <(jq -r '.text' < example.json | xargs -n1 | sort)  | xargs
```

Where `comm -12` prints only lines present in both `file1` and `file2` (where file1 and file2 represents the process substitution `<(code...)`)